Copy the newest versions of multiple files
I am looking for a Batch Script to look after the most recent versions of a file.
The file name is automatically generated and often these files are having multiple versions. I am looking for a way to get the most recent ones.
The file name follows the same pattern:
[ID]_[Week]_[Version]_[Othertext]
example:

12345_2440_01_2_11.csv
12345_2440_02_2_11.csv
12345_2440_03_2_11.csv

Here, 12345 is [ID], 2440 is [Week], 01 is [Version], 2_11 is [Other text]. The most recent one is the one with highest version. In that case 03. Other text isn't relevant, so you can ignore it. The grouping is based on ID, week and version.

34567_2440_01_2_11.csv

34567_2440_02_2_11.csv

34567_2440_03_2_11.csv

34567_2440_04_2_11.csv

34567_2440_05_2_11.csv


Today, I am using a very simple script as I have no idea how many version each file is having - 1 or 20 and then manually deleting the old ones.
copy \\server\folder\subfolder\12345_2440* C:\folder\
copy \\server\folder\subfolder\34567_2440* C:\folder\
set /p=

I am looking a smarter way to copy only what I need.
In the case above, I want to copy 12345_2440_03_2_11.csv and 34567_2440_05_2_11.csv, not all 8 files.
Is there any easy script to do that?

What you've submitted can't be translated into an answerable solution, and answers received thus far are guesses only, and should not be trusted to perform your task. The first thing I'd want to know is the correlation between [ID][Week][Version]_[Othertext] and 12345_2440_01_2_11.csv. That alone impies 12345 is [ID][Week][Version] and 2440_01_2_11 is [Othertext]. When you [Edit] your question to fix that, I also expect that you explain to us, how a script is supposed to determine the 'most recent' ones. Is that according to a substring of the file basename, or by file attributes?

What you've submitted, even with those details fixed, and added, is an off topic direct code request. This site is not a free for hire 'coding to order' service. We help you to fix a reproducible issue with your own code submission. That means you are supposed to research, then write your own code. If that code does not do what was intended of it, that is where this site is supposed to assist you. You submit your code and explain to us how it is failing to achieve the intention, including any debugging, output, results, and essentially everything we need to replicate the reported issue.

Week 2440, seems completely non standard. However there are still things unexplained in your submission. Is the script supposed to be matching all of the file basename components except for the version when grouping, or is it supposed to be matching only some of them. Like I stated previously, there is still insufficient information for a script to be built without making assumptions.

2440 is a year/week format. The code shared by Mofi is working perfectly fine. Thank you so much for your help! Much appreciated!

Why didn't you say that then? It's not as if the information could have been a security issue. Regardless of you having accepted an answer, it doesn't change the fact that your question is lacking. The problem therefore is that moving forward it will be almost impossible for it together with the answer to be useful to future readers. Moreso because Mofi posted three different code examples in their submission. You should also be aware that accepted answers do not close a question. Somebody else may have something more suitable for you and/or future readers, but they need task clarity first.

All three solutions provided below require that the number of version digits is identical for all files with same identifier and week. In the example file names list all files have version numbers with two digits.
There can be used the following batch file if neither source folder path nor destination folder path nor any file name contains one or more !.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=\\server\folder\subfolder"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\folder"
md "!DestinationFolder!" 2>nul
if not exist "!DestinationFolder!\" echo ERROR: Missing folder: "!DestinationFolder!"& exit /B 1
set "ID_Week="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "!SourceFolder!\*_*_*_*.csv" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%I in ("%%G") do if not "!ID_Week!" == "%%I_%%J" set "ID_Week=%%I_%%J" & copy "!SourceFolder!\%%G" "!DestinationFolder!\" 1>nul
endlocal

There can be used the following batch file if source or destination folder path contains one or more ! but no file name is with an exclamation mark.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=\\server\folder\subfolder"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\folder"
md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" echo ERROR: Missing folder: "%DestinationFolder%"& exit /B 1
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "ID_Week="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "!SourceFolder!\*_*_*_*.csv" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%I in ("%%G") do if not "!ID_Week!" == "%%I_%%J" set "ID_Week=%%I_%%J" & copy "!SourceFolder!\%%G" "!DestinationFolder!\" 1>nul
endlocal
endlocal

The following batch file is the slowest but works even with a file name containing one or more exclamation marks in other text part.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=\\server\folder\subfolder"
set "DestinationFolder=C:\folder"
md "%DestinationFolder%" 2>nul
if not exist "%DestinationFolder%\" echo ERROR: Missing folder: "%DestinationFolder%"& exit /B 1
set "ID_Week="
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*_*_*_*.csv" /A-D /B /O-N 2^>nul') do for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%I in ("%%G") do (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if not "!ID_Week!" == "%%I_%%J" (
        endlocal
        set "ID_Week=%%I_%%J"
        copy "%SourceFolder%\%%G" "%DestinationFolder%\" 1>nul
    ) else endlocal
)
endlocal

The main trick is getting a list of matching CSV file names in source folder ordered reverse by name and copy always the first file in the list if the identifier and week part changes in comparison to identifier and week stored currently in environment variable ID_Week.
To understand the commands used and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

copy /?
dir /?
echo /?
endlocal /?
exit /?
for /?
if /?
md /?
set /?
setlocal /?

Read the Microsoft documentation about Using command redirection operators for an explanation of 1>nul and 2>nul. The redirection operator > must be escaped with caret character ^ on FOR command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command FOR which executes the embedded dir command line with using a separate command process started in background with %ComSpec% /c and the command line within ' appended.
Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file explains the unconditional command operator & as used in all code examples. There is no space left to & after command echo as otherwise the command echo would output this space as trailing space too.

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the directories are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"

SET "ID=:"
SET "Week=:"
FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=_" %%g IN (
 'dir /b /a-d /o-n "%sourcedir%\*_*_*_*_*.csv" '
 ) DO (
  CALL :doimoveit %%g %%h
  IF DEFINED moveit ECHO COPY "%sourcedir%\%%g_%%h_%%i" "%destdir%\"
)

GOTO :EOF

::
:: Set moveit to a value if %1 or %2 are different from their prior values
::
:doimoveit

: default - don't move it
SET "moveit="
IF /i "%1" NEQ "%ID%" GOTO moveme
IF /i "%2" NEQ "%Week%" GOTO moveme
GOTO :eof
:moveme
SET "moveit=Y"
SET "ID=%1" 
SET "Week=%2" 
GOTO :eof

Perform a dir listing of the source directory, using the filename mask *_*_*_*_*.csv to locate all of the files fitting your pattern. a-d excludes directories /o-n sorts in reverse-order of name (so that the required file-to-copy appears before any other names with the same ID and week number). /b provides basic data; ie. name only.
See FOR /? from the prompt or thousands of examples on SO for information about how the delims and tokens options work. Essentially, as delims is set to _, then the name delivered by dir will be tokenised, the first token is assigned to %%g, the second to %%h and the remainder of the name to %%i.
The doimoveit subroutine accepts the ID and Week of the file and compares these elements against the prior version encountered (Since : cannot appear in a filename, setting ID and Week to : initially ensures that the very first name encountered is copied)
If the two elements are a repeat of the previous name, moveit remains set to nothing on return from the call. If not, we have a new ID or Week, so set moveit to something and record the new ID and Week.
Using Boolean
The copy is echoed for verification. remove the echo keyword to actually execute the copy.
